# How do I dynamically set a variable's value within a class in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass()
{
  private void SetAValiable(int boolNumber)
  {
    bool b1 = false;
    bool b2 = false;

    ("b" + boolNumber) = true;
  }
}
```

I've tried this but keep getting a null out of the GetProperty call:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
PropertyInfo pinfo = myType.GetProperty("b" + boolNumber);
pinfo.SetValue(myType, true, null);
```

Anyone have any thoughts as to how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: "a variable" and "available" are two very different things. "a valiable" is neither of them.

Comment: b1 and b2 are not properties of MyClass, but variables in SetAValiable.

Answer (score 7):

Use an array, not reflection:

```
public class MyClass()
{
    private void SetAValiable(int boolNumber)
    {
        bool[] b = new bool[2]; //will default to false values
        b[boolNumber] = true;
    }
}
```

It is impossible to use reflection to access local variables as you are trying to do.  They would need to be fields for that to be an option, but even then it still wouldn't be the *right* option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `b1` and `b2` are not members of `MyClass`. That is why you are getting `null`.
You need something like this:

```
public class MyClass()
{
     private bool b1;
     private bool b2;
}
```

Secondly, the first parameter of `setValue` needs to be a instance of the class `MyClass`. In your example it is an instance of `Type`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in the way you described, then you have two options, first is that you can use static fields, but if you can't make use of static fields, the reflection works like this:

```
public T Reflect<T, X> (X Value, int i) { 
   var Fields = typeOf(T).GetFields();
   var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); // let's say you cant create the object the normal way
   Fields[i].setValue(obj, Value);
// then you can cast obj to your type and return it or do whatever you wanna do with it
   return (T) obj;
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have any fields at all.  He has locals.  If he did have fields, he could use reflection, sure.  There would be no need for the fields to be static, nor would there be any need for him to use reflection to create the fields.  Since the code is running in an instance method, he already has an instance.  It's `this`.  Then of course there's the fact that he shouldn't be using reflection to do this in the first place.  He should be using an array.

Comment: @Servy: You'er right, I posted this after reading your answer, but why I did that was because I though maybe this user is interested in learning reflections, so although your answer is the best, he can also learn about reflections by looking at this.

Comment: If he wanted to learn how to use reflection then he needs to be trying to solve problems that should be solved using reflection.  That's how you learn how to use a given tool *properly*.  And of course, your answer has a whole mess of problem involving not solving the problem correctly using reflection, in addition to the fact that you're suggesting its use in the first place.

Comment: @Servy: I did not suggest it, I said if he is interested in what he's currently doing (I don't necessarily recommend it), then he can assign values to fields of another class using reflection this way. So I wrote a generic answer that just shows how reflection in this case works. So if you assume that this user does not know a single thing about C#, and he won't realize that he need to get the boolean types out of that method first, then I think this question has to be closed due to minimal understanding of the problem.

Comment: You suggested the use of a static field, which doesn't seem appropriate at all, and you suggested creating a new instance of the type using reflection, which isn't appropriate, You didn't even provide compilable code as you have spelled operators and methods incorrectly.  If your goal was to explain how to use reflection, you failed to do so.

Comment: @Servy: Thank you very much for your kind advice, next time I will ask for your permission before posting an answer :)

Comment: Apparently you don't value post correct answers to a question.  That's unfortunate.  On this site incorrect and unhelpful answers are not wanted.

Comment: @Servy: I'm the student and you are the master, you are free to flag my answer if you think it doesn't belong here.

Comment: So you're saying that you don't *care* that your answer has very significant problems?  You have no interest in improving your answer to fix those problems, nor the ability to recognize that the answer isn't helpful to simply remove it yourself?

Comment: @Servy: If I were the guy who asked the question, I could easily understand how to solve the problem using reflection by looking at that method. For that reason I don't think there is anything wrong with my answer, meanwhile there is nothing wrong with my code. You are free to think the otherwise, and you are free to downvote this answer, flag it, comment on it etc. As long as I don't see selfishness and a kind of disrespectful tone in your comments, I do enjoy them, but you can't force me to do what you want, coz that's your idea not mine!

Comment: You say that there's nothing wrong with your code, but it doesn't even *compile*.  You don't think that mis-spelling operator and method names in your code is a problem with it?

Comment: @Servy: did you find anything else beside that ? by the way it is not called misspelling, it is lowercase uppercase problem. If you have problem with that, you can suggest me an edit, I will approve that edit.

Comment: Yes, I have already explained a number of other problems with your post, you have continued to ignore them.  If you can't be bothered to fix your own post when you know it's wrong, then what makes you think I'm going to take the time to fix it for you?  You should have pride in the value of your answers, rather than not caring that it's incorrect and unhelpful.

Comment: @Servy: apparently you are the only who thinks so, coz I didn't receive feedback from anyone else. As I said, you can't force me to accept your idea, and I'd like to teach you that.

Comment: Of course I can't force you to do anything, and I'm not trying to force you to do anything.  I'm trying to get you to *want* to do the right thing.  If I just wanted the post deleted I'd vote to delete it myself, which I haven't done.  Do you really think posting a harmful answer, and refusing to fix it or address it just so that you can prove to me that I can't force to you remove it (despite the fact that I actually could if I wanted to) is the right thing to do?

Comment: @Servy: if you think it is "harmful" like for example it can damage one's knowledge of C# or cause harm to one's computer, then there is no point if you don't delete it! If you think the Uppercase O in typeof is that problematic that can make my code "wrong" and not compilable then again why don't you delete my post? It sounds like my answer is too important to you!